# Slow insert performance on a table with a lot of empty nvarchar columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table with 150 columns. Most of them are of type `nvarchar(100) null`, and some are `decimal(20,7) null`

Example:

```
Create table myTable
(
     ID bigint (PK),
     Col1 Nvarchar(100) null,
     Col2 Nvarchar(100) null,
     Col3 Nvarchar(100) null,
     ....
     Col150 nvarchar(100) null
)
```

When I do an insert I insert only in 20 columns. When I try to insert 1 or 2 million records it takes a lot of time (>1 minute with 32gb ram)

When I insert the same amount of records into a temp table it takes just 1-2 seconds.

[image: Clustered index insert]

I also tried to remove primary key but the results are the same. How can I speed up insert into a table with a lot of empty `nvarchar` columns?

Comment: check this article to understand `index` behaviour https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bd9b36db-7b70-43b8-a971-f6c881cde269/disadvantages-of-clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes?forum=sqlgetstarted

Comment: If you have indexes or constraints on these 150 fields, it will slow down inserts and updates. Do you have any indexes or constraints?

Comment: @Paurian, no, just a primary key

Comment: Are the ones that are empty usually the same? If so, have you thought about separating them out into two separate tables? Ie. account and account_details table? When inserting, indexes are not going to help. You may want to try delayed durability if that’s an option but this seems more like a data model issue than anything else.

Comment: Another thing you can look into is partition switching!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a lot of empty columns I'd suggest using XML as a column type if it's possible
    Create table myTable
    (
    ID bigint (PK),
    Col1 XML
    )

This will increase your performances in circumstances you explained.
Since using xml is a greater topic you can read more [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2899/importing-and-processing-data-from-xml-files-into-sql-server-tables/)

Comment: Hi, I cannot change number of columns but I can change datatypes on those columns. I've just changed all empty columns from nvarchar(100) to bit null and performance improved but not by a lot. Is there anything else that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Speaking about the design, this is not the best practice obviously, having hundreds of nullable columns, which will be null most of the times.

So, I may say :

If you can redesign the table, you may :

1. Use one XML column to store all of those nullable columns (as @seesharpguru mentioned)
2. Convert all of those columns into rows in a separate table
3. Use empty strings instead of NULL values, so you can set all the columns NOT NULLABLE

If you don't have any choices, you may :

1. Use BULK INSERT
2. Just wait until finish and let's hope users will be OK with the SLA ;-)

I'm sure there are many options out there, but at least I've gone through all of these solutions before.

Sorry I cannot give you more other than ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you experience massive page splits. Can be confirmed by monitoring (Profiler or DMV).

Too many columns per a table. 
Requires either to:

- redesign the table (normalize or split - Having 4 tables with 40 columns is much faster than 1 table with 150 columns)
- try to defragment the table
- try different fillfactor

Comment: How can I defragment the table? And what fillfactors should be used?